# User isn't Authenticated after Login Symfony 2.3

Tags: php, symfony

I'm studying Symfony 2 and I'm trying to create my authentication user. I'm following the documentation, but if I implement `AdvancedUserInterface` My user is not authenticated, instead if i Use `UserInterface` all works fine.

My Code is:

Controller:

```
public function saveAction(Request $request) {

        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $encodeFactory = $this->container->get('security.encoder_factory');
            $encoder = $encodeFactory->getEncoder($user);
            $user->setPassword($encoder->encodePassword($request->get($form->getName())['password'], $user->getSalt()));
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('index'));
        }
        return array(
            'form' => $form
        );
```

Entity:

```
<?php

namespace FOO\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="FOO\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable {
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="salt", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $salt;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;


    public function __construct(){
        $this->isActive = true;
        $this->salt= md5(uniqid(null, true));
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username) {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get username
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsername() {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * Set salt
     *
     * @param string $salt
     * @return User
     */
    public function setSalt($salt) {
        $this->salt = $salt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get salt
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSalt() {
        return $this->salt;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password) {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword() {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Set isActive
     *
     * @param boolean $isActive
     * @return User
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isActive
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether the user's account has expired.
     *
     * Internally, if this method returns false, the authentication system
     * will throw an AccountExpiredException and prevent login.
     *
     * @return bool true if the user's account is non expired, false otherwise
     *
     * @see AccountExpiredException
     */
    public function isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether the user is locked.
     *
     * Internally, if this method returns false, the authentication system
     * will throw a LockedException and prevent login.
     *
     * @return bool true if the user is not locked, false otherwise
     *
     * @see LockedException
     */
    public function isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether the user's credentials (password) has expired.
     *
     * Internally, if this method returns false, the authentication system
     * will throw a CredentialsExpiredException and prevent login.
     *
     * @return bool true if the user's credentials are non expired, false otherwise
     *
     * @see CredentialsExpiredException
     */
    public function isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether the user is enabled.
     *
     * Internally, if this method returns false, the authentication system
     * will throw a DisabledException and prevent login.
     *
     * @return bool true if the user is enabled, false otherwise
     *
     * @see DisabledException
     */
    public function isEnabled() {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    /**
     * (PHP 5 &gt;= 5.1.0)<br/>
     * String representation of object
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/serializable.serialize.php
     * @return string the string representation of the object or null
     */
    public function serialize() {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->salt,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * (PHP 5 &gt;= 5.1.0)<br/>
     * Constructs the object
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/serializable.unserialize.php
     * @param string $serialized <p>
     * The string representation of the object.
     * </p>
     * @return void
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized) {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->salt
            ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the roles granted to the user.
     *
     * <code>
     * public function getRoles()
     * {
     *     return array('ROLE_USER');
     * }
     * </code>
     *
     * Alternatively, the roles might be stored on a ``roles`` property,
     * and populated in any number of different ways when the user object
     * is created.
     *
     * @return Role[] The user roles
     */
    public function getRoles() {
        return array('ROLE_USER');
    }

    /**
     * Removes sensitive data from the user.
     *
     * This is important if, at any given point, sensitive information like
     * the plain-text password is stored on this object.
     */
    public function eraseCredentials() {

    }
}
```

security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        FOO\UserBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        administrators:
            entity:
                class: FOOUserBundle:User
                property: username
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                    admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        FOO:
            pattern:   ^/             
            anonymous: ~              
            form_login:
                login_path: login                 
                check_path: login_check           
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider 
            logout:
                path:   /logout                  
                target: /                        
            remember_me:
                key:      "%secret%"
                lifetime: 31536000 # 365 giorni in secondi
                path:     /
                domain:   ~ # Defaults to the current domain from $_SERVER
            #anonymous: ~
            #http_basic:
            #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/demo/secured/hello/admin/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
```

Comment: Error message or just not getting authenticated?  Double check that your user is enabled and that the other advanced Non* methods are returning false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On unserializing the constructor of the class is not called. 
You can easily check this by creating a new Object and serialize and unserialize it like this:

```
$user = new \FOO\UserBundle\EntityUser();

var_dump($user);

$serialized = serialize($user);

var_dump($serialized);

$uUser = unserialize($serialized);

var_dump($uUser);

/**
It output something like this:
class FOO\UserBundle\Entity\User#1 (5) {
  private $id =>
  NULL
  private $username =>
  NULL
  private $salt =>
  string(32) "296cb7bebc4aff07a3cc5bb0da746707"
  private $password =>
  NULL
  private $isActive =>
  bool(true)
}
string(107) "C:26:"FOO\UserBundle\Entity\User":68:{a:4:{i:0;N;i:1;N;i:2;N;i:3;s:32:"296cb7bebc4aff07a3cc5bb0da746707";}}"
class FOO\UserBundle\Entity\User#2 (5) {
  private $id =>
  NULL
  private $username =>
  NULL
  private $salt =>
  string(32) "296cb7bebc4aff07a3cc5bb0da746707"
  private $password =>
  NULL
  private $isActive =>
  NULL
}
*/
```

So you have either to add isActive to the serialize/unserialize method, or call the constructor by hand in the unserialize method.

The real problem behind this behaviour, you can find in the AbstractToken class:
Symfony is reloading the user on every request from the configured user provider and set it to the Token instance (which inherit the setUser method from AbstractToken). In this method Symfony, check against the unserialized data if the user changed. If your user implements the AdvancedUserInterface there are additional tests: isAccountNonExpired, isAccountNonLocked, isCredentialsNonExpired AND isEnabled. So your user loaded from the database returns true for isEnabled, the unserialized user returns NULL, which does not equal. In order of that fact the AbstractToken thinks your user changed and set the token to authenticated = false.

Here some code from the AbstractToken:

```
# file vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/AbstractToken.php
<?php

// [...]

namespace Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token;

// [...]

abstract class AbstractToken implements TokenInterface
{
// [...]

    public function setUser($user)
    {
        if (!($user instanceof UserInterface || (is_object($user) && method_exists($user, '__toString')) || is_string($user))) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('$user must be an instanceof UserInterface, an object implementing a __toString method, or a primitive string.');
        }

        if (null === $this->user) {
            $changed = false;
        } elseif ($this->user instanceof UserInterface) {
            if (!$user instanceof UserInterface) {
                $changed = true;
            } else {
                $changed = $this->hasUserChanged($user);
            }
        } elseif ($user instanceof UserInterface) {
            $changed = true;
        } else {
            $changed = (string) $this->user !== (string) $user;
        }

        if ($changed) {
            // From here the user is not authenticated any more
            $this->setAuthenticated(false);
        }

        $this->user = $user;
    }

// [...]

    private function hasUserChanged(UserInterface $user)
    {

    // [...] Some other checks wich are ok

    if ($this->user instanceof AdvancedUserInterface && $user instanceof AdvancedUserInterface) {
            // [...]
            // Here is the problem with the unserialized user
            if ($this->user->isEnabled() !== $user->isEnabled()) {
                return true;
            }
          // [...]
    }


// [...]
}
```

Comment: thanks, it's works, but I Don't understand Why I have to use serialize. I know that symfony save the user in session by the serialize. Can't symfony save in session the user Object without serialize? If I add an another field I have to put this in serialize and unserialize?

Comment: @monkeyUser I updated my answer, after investigating the problem.